# Module 'skfeature.function.similarity_based.fisher_score' has no attribute 'feature_ranking'

Tags: python, feature-selection

I have implemented the following code to compute Fisher score using `skfeature.function` following the steps implemented in [featureselection.asu.edu/tutorial.php](http://featureselection.asu.edu/tutorial.php#)
My code snippet is provided below:

```
pip install skfeature-chappers
from skfeature.function.similarity_based import fisher_score

score = fisher_score.fisher_score(X_train, y_train)
idx = fisher_score.feature_ranking(score)
print(idx)
```

I am getting the following Attribute error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-cd27bc981d22> in <module>()
  1 import skfeature
  ----> 2 idx = fisher_score.feature_ranking(score)
  3 print(idx)

  AttributeError: module 'skfeature.function.similarity_based.fisher_score' has no attribute 
  'feature_ranking'
```

Comment: check my answer, should solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `feature_ranking` doesn't seem to exist but I think you can find `fisher_score` as part of the API which already returns indexes with parameter `mode='rank'`. Try the following, it worked for me -

```
from skfeature.function.similarity_based import fisher_score
from sklearn.datasets import load_diabetes

db = load_diabetes()
y_train = db.target
X_train = db.data

idx = fisher_score.fisher_score(X_train, y_train, mode='rank') #returns rank directly instead of fisher score. so no need for feature_ranking
print(idx)
```

```
array([1, 7, 3, 6, 2, 0, 9, 8, 5, 4])
```

Comment: I was already able to print the scores. What I wanted was to rank features in descending order according to fisher scores and store it in idx which would output the ranking index ultimately enabling me to specify the number of selected features for evaluation purpose like this:                                                                                         `idx = fisher_score.feature_ranking(score)
num_fea = 5
selected_features_train = X_train[:, idx[0:num_fea]]
selected_features_test = X_test[:, idx[0:num_fea]]`

Comment: Can you post the expected output?

Comment: So basically you want the 5 features with the highest fisher score in X_train?

Comment: Yes, I want the 5 features with the highest fisher score in X_train. The output is supposed to be a numpy array with dimensions (number of samples in training set, 5)

Comment: From what I see in the tutorial, the idx is already a rank. The method that you are refering to (feature rank) is depreciated and the fisher_score now returns the 'rank' of the features already. In the tutorial, ```fisher_score.fisher_score(X_train, y_train)``` returns an array like ```[ 13.96904931   0.5376816    0.19923194 ..``` with fisher scores. And , the ```feature_rank``` returns something like ```[1023 1022   31 ...``` which is ranks of features. Now, in the new updated version of the API, it already returns a rank of the features instead of returning fisher scores.

Comment: So please use idx instead of score directly in the code, i have updated my answer

Comment: Also, I must warn you. The code that you are referring to for tutorial is from python 2.7. python2 is officially dead and for good. If you really want to learn something then please find a tutorial on the topic which is python3. else it can seriously damage your knowledge since practices and pythonic thinking has changed drastically

Comment: if this answer and my time spent on this has helped you then do mark it as the right answer.